# numba vstack doesn't work on list of arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numba

It's weird for me vstack doesn't work with Numba when input is a list of array, it only works when the input is a tuple of array. Example code:

```
@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def stack(items):
    return np.vstack(items)

stack((np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])))
```

returns

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

but

```
stack([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])])
```

Throws an error

```
TypingError: No implementation of function Function(<function vstack at 0x0000027271963488>) found for signature:
>>>vstack(reflected list(array(int32, 1d, C)))
```

Since tuple is not supported, I struggled to find a workaround - did I miss something?

Comment: Can't you just use `stack(tuple([....]))` when calling the function.  Does this use of `numba` gain much speed?

Comment: I have a function that calls vstack, and I want to use numba to speed that up. vstack is one of the things that causing the problem and I cannot go around without it.

Comment: Even with tuple input your `stack` is not consistently better than `np.vstack`.  Comparative times for a large tuple of large arrays vary all over the place.  Even when `numba` is faster it's only by a factor of 2.  Is this really a worthwhile thing to work on?

Comment: It's not about speeding up vstack, I have no intention of doing that. The function I want to speed up does sorting using some custom keys with `sorted`. The sorted result is then stacked up using vstack. However, since `sorted` returns a list and `tuple` cannot appear in that function, numba cannot work on that function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround as @hpaulj mentioned:

```
stack(tuple([np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]))

[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In numba, `vstack`, `hstack` and also `concatenate` only support `tuple` as input, while `list` is not supported.

They say this is because numba can not infer the dimension of the stacked array during compiling [[Ref]](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7476). But I doubt that it actually can, because you can do this manually as following.

You can stack `list` in this indirect way:

```py
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np


@njit()
def test_list_stack(i, array_to_be_stacked):
    shape = (i,) + array_to_be_stacked.shape
    list_of_array = [array_to_be_stacked] * i
    stacked_array = np.empty(shape)
    for j in prange(i):
        stacked_array[j] = list_of_array[j]
    return stacked_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_list_stack(10, np.ones((2, 3)))
```

Or you can define a custom function to do the stacking work:

```py
from numba import njit, prange
from numba.typed import List
import numpy as np

@njit()
def stack(list_of_array):
    shape = (len(list_of_array),) + list_of_array[0].shape
    stacked_array = np.empty(shape)
    for j in prange(len(list_of_array)):
        stacked_array[j] = list_of_array[j]
    return stacked_array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Note that you have to use typed list provided by numba here.
    typed_list = List()
    [typed_list.append(np.ones((2, 3))) for _ in range(10)]
    stacked = stack(typed_list)
    print(stacked.shape)
    print(stacked)
```