# Why is Numba failing to compile this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I am trying to compile the following function with Numba:

```
@njit(fastmath=True, nogil=True)
def generate_items(array, start):
    array_positions = np.empty(SIZE, dtype=np.int64)
    count = 0
    while count < SIZE - start:
        new_array = mutate(np.empty(0, dtype=np.uint8))

        if len(new_array) > 0:
            array_positions[count] = len(array)  # <<=== FAILS HERE
            array = np.append(array, np.append(new_array, 255))
            count += 1

    return array, array_positions
```

But it fails on the indicated line above with this error message:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Cannot unify array(uint8, 1d, C) and array(int64, 1d, C) for 'array.3', defined at ...
```

Which doesn't seem to make sense since I'm just assigning an `int` (the result on `len`) to an array that has a `dtype` of `np.int64`?

Note that `array` is of type `np.uint8` - but I'm not assigning the array itself so this message makes no sense to me.

I attempted to refactor to this:

```
tmp = len(array)  # <<=== FAILS HERE
array_positions[count] = tmp
```

But then it fails there... same message.

I also tried replacing `len(array)` by `array.size` since this is a 1d array, but same error.

Can anyone see why this is failing?

I'm on Python 3.7 and Numba 0.50

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numba failing to compile with very strange message - seems like this should work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845828/numba-failing-to-compile-with-very-strange-message-seems-like-this-should-work)

Comment: No, that was a different issue.. I'm not using concatenate on this case.

Comment: `np.append` uses `np.concatenate`.  I'm not sure about `numba`, but in using `np.append` (or any of the concatenate/stack family) in a loop is a bad idea - slow, and often hard to get right.  We recommend collecting the arrays in an list, and doing just **one** concatenate at the end.

Comment: Take a few minutes to look at the python code for `np.append`.  You'll see how, even in `numpy`, it isn't a very good function.  Another thing, when using `concatenate` in `numba`, give it a tuple argument, not a list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62680256/numba-vstack-doesnt-work-on-list-of-arrays

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for the tips, even though the error is in the line above hen I remove that append it stops giving me the error... I've read a number of times that lists should not be used with numba. Is that not the case? Or lists are problematic only when passing arguments to a function?

Comment: I am now on the struggle to get that tuple of length N created haha.. but its progressing, that's what matters. If you have any tips on how to do that, I placed a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852267/how-to-efficiently-create-a-tuple-of-length-n-with-code-that-will-compile-with-n

Also, if you want to move your comment into an answer I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that you use an unsupported function `mutate` ([as stated here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/reference/numpysupported.html)).
Next, as the error says, you try to add arrays with different data types in

```
np.append(array, np.append(new_array, 255))
```

where the `array` is of type `int64` and `new_array` holds values of type `uint8`. If you've used `@jit` it would have showed you a warning of falling to `object` mode, but because you've enforced the `nonpython` mode by using the `@njit` decorator, it throws an error.
Cheers.