# How to efficiently create a tuple of length N with code that will compile with numba?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, numba

I timed two ways to create a tuple of length N.

This is very fast:

```
def createTuple():
    for _ in range(100000):
        tuplex = (0,) * 1000


CPU times: user 439 ms, sys: 1.01 ms, total: 440 ms
Wall time: 442 ms
```

This is very fast, but doesn't compile with Numba:

```
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function mul>) with argument(s) of type(s): (UniTuple(Literal[int](0) x 1), int64)
```

This is much slower:

```
def createTuple():
    for _ in range(100000):
        tuplex = tuple(0 for _ in range(1000))

%time createTuple()


CPU times: user 5.28 s, sys: 3.28 ms, total: 5.29 s
Wall time: 5.29 s
```

And also fails to compile:

```
The use of yield in a closure is unsupported.
```

I am very new to Python and Numba. Is there a way to get a tuple of length N (known at compile time) create - hopefully efficiently - with Numba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [numba (0.50) documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html):

> Note
>
> The `tuple()` constructor itself is NOT supported.

So, in numba code, tuples need to be either supplied as function arguments or initialized as literals, like `(0, 1, 2, 3)`. This is unfortunate, because it means that operations involving array shapes require tuples in numba, even though they work fine with int arrays in regular numpy:

```
shape = np.arange(1, 4)
np.zeros(shape) # OK for normal python code, not in an @njit function.
```

You'll have to refactor your code to have tuple creation outside the @njit function:

```
@njit
def foo(tup):
   ...

foo(tuple(np.zeros(100)))
```

Unfortunately, `tuple(np.zeros(100))` is relatively slow.

Comment: ah, perfect.. I can create that outside then. Thanks!